# WordPress plugin to have a gallery, in which each image's caption is a whole post?

Tags: wordpress, gallery

I have a post like a gallery, but each image has an analysis for it. That analysis is like a post itself, with headings, paragraphs and some even have galleries within. I can make the post a series of post, but I would like to preserve the navigation between images like a gallery (forward/backward buttons and/or black background).

So far, using the built-in gallery, it's like this:

[image]

Clicking on one particular image, the caption is only one line:

[image]

I imagine my preferred outcome would be Facebook album:

[image]

Is there a plugin for that?

<sup>Also asked on WordPress Stack Exchange: [How to have a gallery in which each image's caption is a whole “post”?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/357586/64282)</sup>

Comment: But they already are posts! In WordPress, when you upload an image it creates a post of type `attachment`, and these posts have URLs, templates, etc, if you just link the gallery to the attachment page, you can display a template, that might even rip off the Instagram. Most people are unaware of it, but some  people use it to allow user to comment, download originals, view EXIF data, etc